# How can I run emacs with no shell?

Tags: emacs, sudoedit

I'm administrating an Arch Linux server.

How can I securely add emacs to my `/etc/sudoers` editor variable? Currently I have "emacs" but that allows `M-x shell`. Basically, I want something like `rvim`, but for emacs.

Comment: How does that help? They could just write a new `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/sudoers` if they have access to write files as root.

Comment: I'd try to answer this but there are a lot of directions. Take a look at this post, I believe it has what you're looking for: http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2011/12/system-administration-with-emacs.html

Comment: @jordanm it could help if you allow only one file e.g. allowing `[editor] /etc/pacman.conf` instead of just `[editor]`.

Comment: @slm that's about opening write-protected files _with_ sudo in Emacs. I want an Emacs with no shell suitable for running _under_ sudo.

Comment: OK, thanks for checking it out, I don't use emacs but know what you're looking for similar to rvim. I'll keep looking.

Comment: if you only allow runing `editor /etc/foo`, that still runs the editor as root and doesn't prevent it from opening other files. If you want to give a user access to write a file, use ACLs, not `sudo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't do that.

Emacs is a Lisp Interpreter that runs an editor (which is written in emacs lisp),
so every time you use emacs, you have access to the the lisp interpreter itself.

That interpreter can do all kinds of things: create/remove files or directories, change access rights etc... Basically, once you're inside emacs, you do not need to have access to a shell to do considerable damage - emacs itself is powerful enough.

Your best bet is probably to find a small emacs clone (for example here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsImplementations ) that supports restricted editing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Emacs is so powerful that (even if shell is disabled) you can do many things.

Maybe the proper solution is to build a wrapper that copies the sudoers file, giving proper permissions, and then run Emacs as a special user that only has permissions to write that file, and at the end copy back the file after verification.

However security-wise: It should be obvious that any sudoers editor can assign *any* permissions, so I wonder what problem you are actually trying to fix.

Still, I made an experiment:
If you set `SHELL` to `/bin/false`, then the Emacs' `shell` command exits with an error immediately as it tries to execute `$SHELL`.